# What does the -ObjC linker flag do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, compiler-construction

I have an app that works with and without the linker flag.  However, without the linker flag, I get a very different behaviour when adding data to a view.

Comment: bensarz, you get a _different_ behaviour without the linker flag... What does that mean?? Different how?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

> This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes.

From this [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html)

Comment: Great! Thank you.  Is this caused by the fact that we are using GCC 4.2 as a compiler?  Would using LLVM GCC 4.2 or LLVM Compiler 2.0 solve the problem?  Or am I mixing up stuff that shouldn't be mixed?

Comment: I think that the behavior is the same with both compilers (besides, I don't know if there are 2 different linkers)...

Comment: Does this mean that you would never need `-ObjC` in anything other than a library / SDK?  I.e. you should never need to use it in an actual app target?

Comment: No, this means you need -ObjC in any project implementing a library that has a category or embedded framework in it

Comment: Just found this out the hard way!