# Yet another - “Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance” issue

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, avplayer

I've looked at each posted question on this topic, but none give me a solution.
My project replicates to a large extent the AVPlayer demo app in the dev library (minus the scrubbing capabilities): I have a copy and paste `AVPlayerDemoPlaybackView` class (renamed `YOPlaybackView`) and an associated controller, along with a very similar xib (minus the scrubber).
My view controller code follows very closely the pattern in the demo (code differences only posted below for brevity).

- I have ensured the view controller is the file's owner
- I have made sure outlets are not duplicated
- I have checked that the view controller is a valid instance by putting a breakpoint in `dealloc`

  The error occurs in the `observeValueForKeyPath` method when the current item for the player changes/will change. The following line gives the error "-[UIView SetPlayer:]": unrecognised selector sent to instance ..."

  ```
       [playbackView setPlayer:player];
  ```

If I create an instance of that view just prior to this call, I don't get the error:

```
        YOPlaybackView* vw = [[YOPlaybackView alloc] init];
        [playbackView setPlayer:player];
```

It seems to me that it might be something to do with nib lazy loading (and creating an instance kicks it in to life).

Looking in the debugger window, playbackView seems to be valid with and without the extra line that creates an (unused) instance.

[image]

Can anyone help progress my object/app lifecycle knowledge please?

---

**Edit - in response to proposed answer containing IB comment**

This is a snap of the IB, showing the view hierarchy and correctly named custom view in the inspector.
[image]

**Edit - in response to question about valid SetPlayer**

The view class in question looks like this:

```
 @class AVPlayer;

 @interface YOPlaybackView : UIView
 @property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer* player;
 - (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player;
 @end
```

and impl:

```
 @implementation YOPlaybackView

 + (Class)layerClass
 {
   return [AVPlayerLayer class];
 }

 - (AVPlayer*)player
 {
   return [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] player];
 }

 - (void)setPlayer:(AVPlayer*)player
 {
   [(AVPlayerLayer*)[self layer] setPlayer:player];
 }

 @end
```

**Edit - output log**

```
2013-07-23 12:05:39.084 iOSVideoPlayerExample[8331:14003] Unknown class YOPlaybackView in Interface Builder file.
2013-07-23 12:05:39.956 iOSVideoPlayerExample[8331:14003] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <YOMasterViewController: 0x985aa10>.
2013-07-23 12:05:40.428 iOSVideoPlayerExample[8331:14003] <UIView: 0x8383900; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8381710>>
2013-07-23 12:05:40.429 iOSVideoPlayerExample[8331:14003] -[UIView setPlayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8383900
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do you have a valid `setPlayer` method in your `YOPlaybackView` subclass?

Comment: I have added the class declaration and implementation as an edit - thanks.

Comment: What is missing is the line where it says `YOPlaybackView * playbackView = ....`

Comment: As I mention in my answer `playbackView` is not pointing to an instance of `YOPlaybackView`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixLam for the help. As I understood it, the classes in the nib, including YOPlaybackView, are created by the framework when the nib is loaded? In the Apple demo app there is no explicit creation of their AVPlayerDemoPlaybackView in any code, so I based my assumption on that. This view has a toolbar child for instance, and that gets automatically created - I don't need to explicitly create a UIToolbar in my code?

Comment: You're sure it's the above line giving the error and not something inside setPlayer, et al?

Comment: @HotLicks - yes I have put a try-catch block round "[playbackView setPlayer:player];" to catch and view the exception.

Comment: The delay seems to be related to instantiating AVAudioPlayer for the first time. If I load any audio, run `[audioPlayer prepareToPlay]` and then immediately release it, the load times for all of my other audio is very close to imperceptible. So now I'm doing that in applicationDidFinishLaunching and everything else runs well.

Comment: It would be good to see the call stack at the time of this error, to know where in the load sequence you're invoking this function.  I'm wondering if there's a timing problem of some sort, and the extra alloc/init just provides a time delay.

Comment: Hi I am also facing same issue. Earlier when I was running my app on iOS 8.x.x everything works fine but when I switched to iOS 9, app is getting crash with same error as above mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `playbackView` appears to be an instance of `UIView` which does not have a method called `setPlayer:`. Check that you are creating an instance of your own subclass of `UIView`. Could you post the snippet of code where you create the `playbackView`?

If you are using Interface Builder make sure that you have set the correct class in the inspector.

You will need to reference the class somewhere in your code. Try Adding `[YOPlaybackView class]` right above the `setPlayer:` call.

Comment: Yes I'm using IB. I have a top level view (UIView) with a child view (YOPlaybackView - set in inspector). My file owner is changed to my custom view controller, and my outlets are correctly wired up as far as I can see (double-checked). Added snapshot of IB.

Comment: Can you add `NSLog(@"%@", playbackView);` just before the setPlayer call and post the output

Comment: Now getting somewhere - added as edit to question. Seems the IB file doesn't know what the class YOPlaybackView is-(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Using @FelixLam's very helpful advice I managed to get more log output data, which is now inserted as the third edit in the question. The first line output states that the Interface Builder does not know what my custom view class was. With a bit of searching on the site I came across the answer to that problem here (["Unknown class <MyClass> in Interface Builder file" error at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725881/unknown-class-myclass-in-interface-builder-file-error-at-runtime)) - which turns out to be the answer to my question as well.

In short, the linker flag "-ObjC" must be added to the project, which forces the linker to load the members of the class.

Comment: Hi @FelixLam, once again thanks for helping. For my understanding, can you explain why your proposal of adding e.g. "[YOPlaybackView class]" to kick it in to life is a better solution than adding the inker flag -ObjC? Is it for efficiency sake so that you are not loading everything? Thanks

Comment: This leads to smaller binaries and avoids loading everything. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629979/what-does-the-objc-linker-flag-do