# [AVPlayerViewController setPlayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

[AVPlayerViewController setPlayer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101b91980 error.

I am trying to play a video using AVPlayerViewController.

```
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController* avPlayerView;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb" ofType:@"mp4"];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];

AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

_avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
[AVPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
self.avPlayerView = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
self.avPlayerView.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.avPlayerView setPlayer:_avPlayer];
[self.view addSubview:_avPlayerView.view];
```

but it is crashing. If i use same code in a new project, video play nicely.What is the problem?Please help.

Comment: Is your project linked against AVKit?

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: In your project, is the target you're building set to link against AVKit? Check the Build Phases.

Comment: Bro, I m really sorry. I checked out my target's build phases. But i don't understand. I can't figure out link against AVKit. Please help me to figure out this. I really need this.

Comment: Build Phases. Link Binary With Libraries. Make sure AVFoundation and AVKit are both in there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import **AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h** and **AVKit/AVKit.h** in your controller and try to assign a player to playerController like this.

```
self.avPlayerView.player = self.avPlayer;
```

Instead of adding observer to AVPlayer Class add observer to Avplayer instance.

```
[avPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

Comment: still crashing.

Comment: make sure file path is not empty and you may find help from this also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807402/yet-another-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-issue

Comment: No.... same crash. I think my problem is in frameworks which said by  @CharlesSrstka . but i can't figure out.

Comment: I think it is this line: `[AVPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];` If you do this you need to implement `observeValueForKeyPath: ofObject: change: context:` in your `self` object.