# iOS native app, integrating with Cordova 2.9.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uiwebview, json

I have created a native iOS app (Xcode 5.1), and I want to open via a btn, a cordova(Cordova 2.9.0) web view(Otherwise CDVViewController). I've succeed this and the web view works and it shows me the webpage, but when I embed the cordova.js (inside the webpage), the 
CDVCommandQueue.m

```
- (void)fetchCommandsFromJs
{
// Grab all the queued commands from the JS side.
NSString* queuedCommandsJSON = [_viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    @"cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeFetchMessages()"];
NSLog(@"---- %@",queuedCommandsJSON);
[self enqueCommandBatch:queuedCommandsJSON];
if ([queuedCommandsJSON length] > 0) {
    CDV_EXEC_LOG(@"Exec: Retrieved new exec messages by request.");
}
}
```

calls the above function and it executes the 'cordova.require('cordova/exec').nativeFetchMessages()', 
this function returns

```
[["Device748313476","Device","getDeviceInfo",[]],["NetworkStatus748313477","NetworkStatus","getConnectionInfo",[]]]
```

and then it passes this value to

```
- (void)executePending
{
// Make us re-entrant-safe.
if (_currentlyExecuting) {
    return;
}
@try {
    _currentlyExecuting = YES;

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_queue count]; ++i) {
        // Parse the returned JSON array.
        NSLog(@"%@",[_queue objectAtIndex:i]);
        **NSArray* commandBatch = [[_queue objectAtIndex:i] JSONObject];**

        // Iterate over and execute all of the commands.
        for (NSArray* jsonEntry in commandBatch) {
            CDVInvokedUrlCommand* command = [CDVInvokedUrlCommand commandFromJson:jsonEntry];
            CDV_EXEC_LOG(@"Exec(%@): Calling %@.%@", command.callbackId, command.className, command.methodName);

            if (![self execute:command]) {
#ifdef DEBUG
                    NSString* commandJson = [jsonEntry JSONString];
                    static NSUInteger maxLogLength = 1024;
                    NSString* commandString = ([commandJson length] > maxLogLength) ?
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@[...]", [commandJson substringToIndex:maxLogLength]] :
                        commandJson;

                    DLog(@"FAILED pluginJSON = %@", commandString);
#endif
            }
        }
    }

    [_queue removeAllObjects];
} @finally
{
    _currentlyExecuting = NO;
}
}
```

My app is crashing because on this line

```
NSArray* commandBatch = [[_queue objectAtIndex:i] JSONObject];
```

doesn't recognize the value as json object and it gives me this error message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString JSONObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

*Had the same recently, while was building old cordova app in new Xcode.*

You should check `Other linker flags` in Your target settings:

[image: Other linker flags]

For the `debug` build configuration You could use `-ObjC` flag. ([What does the -ObjC linker flag do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629979/what-does-the-objc-linker-flag-do), [Why do I get a runtime exception of "selector not recognized" when linking against an Objective-C static library that contains categories?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html))

If after reading previous links, You still want to use this flag in `release` — just do it.

Otherwise, You should add `-force_load ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libCordova.a` to the release linker flag.

In order to check/edit active build configuration go to `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit scheme` (`Cmd <`).

Comment: Thank you for including the -force_load path syntax, I was having difficulty with that.