# Unity iOS build error: duplicate symbols when using Firebase Unity SDK + Google VR SDK for Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase, google-vr

I'm working on an **Unity project** where I'm using the **Google VR SDK for Unity** and the `FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage` from the **Firebase SDK for Unity**.

This combination of Google SDK's throws a `duplicate symbols` error when I try to build for iOS.

---

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to reproduce the error:

**Requirements:**

- iOS device (version 7.0 or later)
- Computer with macOS
- Latest [Unity](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal) version (5.5.2f1)
- Latest [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) version (8.2.1)

**Steps:**

1. [Download](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download) the Google VR SDK for Unity (v1.20).
2. [Download](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) the Firebase SDK for Unity (v3.0.0).
3. Unzip the Firebase SDK for Unity.
4. Open Unity and create a new project.
5. Go to *File > Build Settings...* , select iOS and click on Switch Platform.
6. Open *Player Settings...* and set a *Bundle Identifier*.
7. Go to *Assets > Import Package > Custom package...* , select the `GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage` and import all except the *Demos* folder.
8. A Pop-Up window will appear. Select *I Made a Backup, Go Ahead!*.
9. Another Pop-Up window will appear. Select *Import Package* and *Import* all.
10. Go to *Assets > Import Package > Custom package...* , select the unzipped `FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage` and import all of it.
11. *File > Save project*
12. Connect the iOS device to the computer.
13. *File > Build & Run*
14. The Xcode build will fail because the project needs a signing with a team. Set it in your Xcode project to a valid one.
15. Press the Xcode play button to build & run the project on your connected iOS device.

---

The project build on Xcode will end with the following error:

> 25 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

The architecture changes depending of the connected iOS device, but the error is the same.

[image: Error screenshot]

---

- Is there something that we can do?
- Is it an error that must be resolved by Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the GVR sdk. The problem is that GVR was released including the transitive dependencies, some of which other SDKs at google (or elsewhere) depend on as well, such as firebase. Since Unity doesn't have any package management for this, we've rolled our own:

https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

However GVR sdk isn't yet using this to include its transitive dependencies and so we get the conflicts.

I'm working on a fix that makes the IOSResolver above, detect this in GVR and strip the objects that should not be included.

In the meantime, here's a work-around you can use to strip the redundant objects yourself:

1. Locate: libgvrunity.a in Assets/Plugins/iOS/libgvrunity.a
2. Create a shell script in the folder with the following contents:

   ```
   set -ex
   lipo libgvrunity.a -thin armv7 -output libgvrunity-armv7.a
   lipo libgvrunity.a -thin arm64 -output libgvrunity-arm64.a

   ar -t libgvrunity-armv7.a | grep 'GTMLogger\|GTMSession' | xargs ar -dv libgvrunity-armv7.a
   ar -t libgvrunity-arm64.a | grep 'GTMLogger\|GTMSession' | xargs ar -dv libgvrunity-arm64.a

   lipo libgvrunity.a -replace armv7 libgvrunity-armv7.a -replace arm64 libgvrunity-arm64.a -output libgvrunity-fat.a

   rm libgvrunity-armv7.a libgvrunity-arm64.a

   mkdir -p backup
   mv libgvrunity.a backup
   mv libgvrunity-fat.a libgvrunity.a
   ```
3. Build and run from Unity again.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 :Go to build Settings and search for "No Common Blocks" and set it no

Option 2:

1. Go to Build Phases in Target settings.
2. Go to “Link Binary With
       Libraries”.
3. Check if any of the libraries exist twice.
4. Build again.

Option 3:

1. Removed -ObjC from Other linker flag.

Comment: The Unity iOS build already sets `No Common Blocks` to `No` by default, so this doesn't solve the error. Also I have already tried setting it to `Yes`, nothing changes.

Comment: try to remove -ObjC from Other Linker Flags

Comment: I have also tried that, the app builds successfully without the `-objC` flag, but then crashes on start.

Comment: then your problem is solved you can create new question for the error you got, btw what error did you got on crash ?

Comment: Well, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629979/what-does-the-objc-linker-flag-do) if I remove the `-ObjC` flag the SDK's and libraries will not be loaded. So the build would not throw the error because the libraries would not be loaded. That's not a solution.