# New error on duplicate symbol using firebase sdk and googlevr sdk

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-vr-sdk

I got this error when I follow this: [Unity iOS build error: duplicate symbols when using Firebase Unity SDK + Google VR SDK for Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516646/unity-ios-build-error-duplicate-symbols-when-using-firebase-unity-sdk-google), I also experience the same duplicate symbols using Firebase SDK and GoogleVr SDK:

```
"_kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from: ___43-[IonNetworkHelper makeRequest:requestPtr:]_block_invoke in libgvrunity.a(ionnetworkhelper.mm.o) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from: objc-class-ref in libgvrunity.a(ionnetworkhelper.mm.o)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: look at this stackoverlow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516646/unity-ios-build-error-duplicate-symbols-when-using-firebase-unity-sdk-google

Comment: @RaduDiță yes i have done the solution given by jonhb003 but after build in xcode i still have the error posted above. Thanks.